# RequireJS : reading property from file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

```
define(["io/cor/extensions", "gettext!io/cor"], function (ext, g) {
    "use strict";

    require(["io/cor/config"], function (xConfig) {
        xConfig.load().done(function(temp) {
            console.log("value:", xConfig.get("ui.branding.enabled"));
        });
    });
});
```

I have "ui.branding.enabled" property in `ovf.properties` and at this location there are various other property files available. In the above code I can see that `oxConfig.get("ui.branding.enabled")` is reading property.

I am unable to understand which property file `xConfig` is looking in. I cannot see mapping of property file and `xConfig` in my code.

Comment: Change oxConfig to xConfig.

Comment: oh..it was a typo mistake in the post.Any inputs ?

Comment: "io/cor/config", isnt that the AMD module you are looking for xConfig. That will be path of the file if you haven't done any path configurations for RequireJS.

Comment: @ vishwanath : Didn't get you.It is requested to explain plz

Comment: What are those `"io/cor/..."` modules? What's the implementation of `"io/cor/config"`?

Comment: @ kryger : No these are separate modules